# Is there a way to create a grid of graphs with plots I already made?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, formatting, box

I am trying to put together 4 plots that  made into one box that has all 4 shrunk into one image. e
I tried to just enter the names of my plots as arguments (ex. wshot_plot) but that does not work.

```
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
    axs[0, 0].plot(wshot_plot)
    axs[0, 0].set_title('Wrist')
    axs[0, 1].plot(slshot_plot)
    axs[0, 1].set_title('Slap')
    axs[1, 0].plot(snshot_plot)
    axs[1, 0].set_title('Snap')
    axs[1, 1].plot(tshot_plot)
    axs[1, 1].set_title('Tip-In')
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Desired output is something like this (with completed graphs of course)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import e, pi, sin, exp, cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = [1.02, .95, .87, .77, .67, .46, .74, .60]
b = [0.39, .32, .27, .22, .18, .15, .13, .12]
c = [0.49, .42, .37, .32, .28, .35, .33, .52]
d = [0.29, .52, .47, .52, .58, .35, .43, .32]


python_course_green = "#476042"
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))

t = np.arange(-5.0, 1.0, 0.1)

sub1 = fig.add_subplot(221) # instead of plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
sub1.set_title('Something A') # non OOP: plt.title('The function f')
sub1.plot(a)


sub2 = fig.add_subplot(222, facecolor="lightgrey")
sub2.set_title('Something B')
sub2.plot(b)


t = np.arange(-3.0, 2.0, 0.02)
sub3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
sub3.set_title('Something C')
sub3.plot(c)

t = np.arange(-0.2, 0.2, 0.001)
sub4 = fig.add_subplot(224, facecolor="lightgrey")
sub4.set_title('Something D')
sub4.plot(d)



plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Output**

I hope I could help you out on this.

[image]

Comment: what is the np.arange for?

Comment: With the .arrange( ) function you can customize the steps on the x and y axis. --> https://ibb.co/nz80ts0